# <textarea> values not posting with form

Tags: html

Feel like I must be missing something here as it's such a simple thing

**Code**

```
<form action="/configurations" method="post" id="metricConfigForm">
    <table>
        <thead>
            ...
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% for (var i = 0; i < resultNo; i++) { %>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="hidden" id="years" name="years" value="<%= results[i].YEAR %>"/></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" id="ids" name="ids" value="<%= results[i].ID %>"/></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" id="metRowID" name="metRowID" value="<%= results[i].METRIC_ROW_INDEX %>"/></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" id="prodComID" name="prodComID" value="<%= results[i].PRODUCT_COMPONENT_ID %>"/></td>
                    <td><textarea id="sources" name="sources" disabled><%= results[i].SOURCE %></textarea></td>
                    <td><textarea id="metrics" name="metrics" disabled><%= results[i].KPI_METRIC %></textarea></td>
                    <td><textarea id="descriptions" name="descriptions" disabled><%= results[i].DESCRIPTON %></textarea></td>
                    <td><textarea id="comments" name="comments" disabled><%= results[i].COMMENTS %></textarea></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="manualTickTemp" name="tick" value="<%= results[i].MANUAL %>"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="targetTemp" name="target" value="<%= results[i].TARGET_VALUE %>" disabled/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="manualTemp" name="manual" value="<%= results[i].MANUAL_VALUE %>" disabled/></td>
                </tr>
            <% } %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

I have no idea why but the only values being posted back in this form are the **first 4 `inputs`**. The `textarea`'s and anything below that (the other `input`'s) are not being posted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot post form elements with `disabled` attribute. Instead use `readonly` on them. Eg:

```
<textarea id="sources" name="sources" readonly>
```

And you can style them like `disabled` using CSS:

```
[readonly] { /* style as disabled */ }
```

Or, have a same name with hidden `<input />` fields:

```
<textarea id="sources" name="sources" disabled>
<input type="hidden" value="^ textarea's value" name="sources" />
```

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't know about `readonly`..learn something new everyday. I have chnaged the `textarea`'s but now my `input` (`name="tick`) is not posting either

Comment: @WillAshworth Checkboxes get posted **only** if they are checked. Else they won't be posted.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan That's what I have given. `:)`

Comment: Thank you!! I'll add a bit of jQuery then to post something else if it's not checked

Comment: @WillAshworth You can check if the posted checkbox value is null, then it is not checked. Else it is checked.

Comment: @WillAshworth The value of most of the browsers for `checkbox` is `on`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar thank you again!! And will add jQuery to suit what I need

Answer (score 0):

`disabled` form controls are not successful controls and will not be included in submitted form data. Remove the `disabled` attributes.

You might want to look at the `readonly` attribute.